# how to run Dask pypy

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, pypy

I am new to the Dask framework, therefore, kindly forgive me if my question sounds silly to you.

Currently, I am using Dask-distributed (2020.12.0 from conda) to run my task in LocalCluster, which is quite fast, but my concern is related to the pypy support with Dask. As I saw the GitHub blog by [@mrocklin](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/854) where it is stated that if we use pypy to run Dask scheduler than we can get a speedup of around 2X-5X. But my concern is how to register Dask-scheduler to use pypy.
I also visited the Dak documentation but not able to find the required solution. Currently, I created a conda environment with pypy ([Blog](https://www.glennklockwood.com/data-intensive/analysis/dask.html)), but not able to use pypy with Dask.

if there is some script or modification required to register scheduler (as we write to for cython), kindly let me know.

Kindly advise me in this regard, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: I created the pypy3.6 environment with conda, and installed the dask in this environment. Then I manually set dependency for h5py and used pypy interpreter to run dask , but getting some weird errors (especially **kwargs incompatible error with pypy). I just want to run dask schedular with pypy.

Comment: h5py is not really compatible with pypy, see https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1591. It is hard to turn "weird errors" into something I can comment on. Can you paste more of the traceback?